# SolrNet: SolrConnectionException (400) bad request when attempting to Add and Commit

Tags: c#, .net, solr, tomcat7, solrnet

I have gotten to the point where SolrNet executes the "Add" method but when I try to "Commit" is when I receive the error. The following is my schema.xml, model, code calling it, and the error I get. Even stranger is that despite the error, the model is added to my Solr index AFTER I restart Tomcat (so it still adds my model despite the error but not immediately):

schema.xml (fields and fieldtypes):

```
<!-- Fields -->   
<field name="part_numbers" type="my_string_exact" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="page_url" type="my_string_exact" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="product_name" type="my_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<!-- FieldTypes -->
<fieldType name="my_string_exact" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="my_string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="my_int" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true" />
```

Model (Product.cs) *NOTE - PageId uses the Solr default "id" that is a string, unique and required:

```
public class Product
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string PageId { get; set; }

    [SolrField("part_numbers")]
    public ICollection<string> PartNumbers { get; set; }

    [SolrField("page_url")]
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }

    [SolrField("product_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code initializing, calling the Add and Commit *NOTE - This is a unit test so init is only called once:

```
Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8080/solr");
Product testProd = new Product() { 
            EPiPageId = "44", 
            Name = "TestProd3", 
            PageUrl = "/TestProd3", 
            PartNumbers = new List<string>() { "000022222", "000000333333" } 
        };
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
solr.Add(testProd);
solr.Commit(); // Bad Request Error occurs here.
```

Error Msg:

```
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
  Source=SolrNet
  StackTrace:
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 104
       at SolrNet.Commands.CommitCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Commands\CommitCommand.cs:line 71
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Send(ISolrCommand cmd) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrBasicServer.cs:line 87
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrBasicServer.cs:line 91
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Commit(CommitOptions options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrBasicServer.cs:line 54
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Commit() in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrServer.cs:line  24
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse() in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\HttpWebAdapters\Impl\HttpWebRequestAdapter.cs:line 36
            at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 160
            at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 101
       InnerException:
```

**EDIT** Thanks to Paige for the answer: The issue was a "waitFlush" error that is a bug with older versions of SolrNet. The version of SolrNet that I was using was from VS NuGet that was 0.3.1 (which I assumed was their latest stable build). Their google code site does not have their most recent build but the build server (here: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1 under "artifacts") did have the latest with the fix to this bug. Problem solved for me.

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#im-getting-a-bad-request-error-when-calling-commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you are probably seeing a `waitFlush` error in your Tomcat Logs and you are using version 4.X of Solr. If that is the case, this is a known issue with Solr 4.x and older versions of SolrNet. To fix this issue, upgrade to a later release of the SolrNet library. You can download it from the [Build Server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1). Click on Artifacts to get a link to the zip.

Comment: I checked the version that I am getting from NuGet (I got SolrNet from a NuGet package in VS) and it's version 0.3.1. I see from their google code (https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) that they have a 0.4.0 but it looks like it's still in beta. Was this issue present for 0.3.1 and fixed on 0.4.0? I'll try out 0.4.0.

Comment: Ok now it works. The build server had the correct version (unlike NuGet or their google code that both did not have the most recent from the looks of it). Thanks Paige.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the release that fixes the Solr 4.X waitFlush error has not been released yet.