# SolrNet commit error with waitFlush

Tags: c#, tomcat7, solrnet

First of all, ich have tried som published solutions like this:

- [SolrNet: SolrConnectionException (400) bad request when attempting to Add and Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682501/solrnet-solrconnectionexception-400-bad-request-when-attempting-to-add-and-co)
- https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=172
- and so one

I have no access to the Build Server, seams to be down. So i work with the fIles that i get.

First i have testet the Nuget Package version. (Oldes one) I get the errors.

After that i load the current version from the guthub repo version 0.4.0.2002

I always get the excaption with the 400 Bad Request and the waitFlush error.

My Code looks like that:

```
public void SolrInitialSetup()
    {
        if (doorValue)
        {
            try
            {
                Startup.Init<Document>("http://localhost:8080/solr");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Solr Connection successfull!");
                doorValue = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Solr Connection failed with error: " + e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Solr Connection already exist!");
        }

        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
        var docList = sampledocsDb.Docs.ToList();
        foreach (var doc in docList)
        {
            var d = new Document()
            {
                Id = doc.FieldId,
                Title = doc.FieldTitle,
                Content = doc.FieldContent
            };
            solr.Add(d);
            solr.Commit(); 
        }


    }
```

Comment: Build server is working fine: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#im-getting-a-bad-request-error-when-calling-commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Strange. The Build Server is now online. Perhaps down yesterday. Now with that Build it works fine.

Problem is that it is the same version number, but it is an other version. When a new Version is published, they should increment the Build Version Number.